# Is there a way to increase/decrease the value of CSS line-height with jQuery each time an element is clicked?

Tags: jquery, css

Adding either of the operators += or -= doesn't work. I figure it must have something to do with the line-height property itself. Thought I would post here to see whether a) I was just being stupid or b) someone would be able to help me with some sort of workaround (ideally, the text field would still be responsive).

Here's what I have code-wise: https://jsfiddle.net/448ftbz6/

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#up").click(function(){
        $("#paragraph p").css({"line-height":"75%"});
        });
    $("#down").click(function(){
        $("#paragraph p").css("line-height":"150%")
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="paragraph">
    <div id="arrows">
        <div id="up">less</div><br>
        <div id="down">more</div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sed felis semper, sodales mi sed, bibendum eros. Nunc malesuada ligula nisl, vel vehicula ipsum gravida non. Praesent mollis orci arcu, id fermentum lectus auctor sit amet. Suspendisse ultrices cursus purus quis consequat. Suspendisse placerat eget lorem vel euismod. Morbi volutpat nisl nulla, at fermentum erat imperdiet varius. Donec non porttitor mi. Nam iaculis turpis sit amet lacus luctus, nec consequat sapien ultricies. Duis placerat ut mauris eget scelerisque.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The jQuery seems to work, so that's not the issue; it just isn't doing what I want it to do. Ideally, when one clicked the "less" or "more" button, the line-height would simply decrease or increase from what it previously was. However, it seems I can only set one value. Does anyone know of anything I might be able to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#up").click(function(){
        $("#paragraph p").css({"line-height":$("#paragraph p").height()*0.75+"%"});
 });
    $("#down").click(function(){
     $("#paragraph p").css("line-height", $("#paragraph p").height()*1.5+"%")
 });
});
```

```css
#arrows {
 float: right;
}
#up, #down {
    height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: #FF00FF;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="paragraph">
<div id="arrows">
    <div id="up">less</div><br>
<div id="down">more</div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sed felis semper, sodales mi sed, bibendum eros. Nunc malesuada ligula nisl, vel vehicula ipsum gravida non. Praesent mollis orci arcu, id fermentum lectus auctor sit amet. Suspendisse ultrices cursus purus quis consequat. Suspendisse placerat eget lorem vel euismod. Morbi volutpat nisl nulla, at fermentum erat imperdiet varius. Donec non porttitor mi. Nam iaculis turpis sit amet lacus luctus, nec consequat sapien ultricies. Duis placerat ut mauris eget scelerisque.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great, but for some reason it goes bonkers in a smaller window - the "up" button starts expanding the spacing instead of contracting it. Why might this be?

Answer (score 0):

Yup!

https://jsfiddle.net/stephm/448ftbz6/2/

You need to first set an initial line-height to p. Then on click, you get the line height and add 10px or take away 10px from it. For example, this decreases the line height by 10px each click:

```
$("#up").click(function(){
    var curLineHeight = $('p').css('line-height');
    $("#paragraph p").css('line-height', (parseInt(curLineHeight, 10) - 10) + 'px');

});
```

Comment: Seems like you're on the right path, however this is increasing/decreasing by 10px and not a percentage.

Comment: @j08691 is it % as i been working pixels, then we need some math

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on it  **[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/448ftbz6/3/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // click handler for element with id #up
    $("#up").click(function () {
        var newLineHeight = calculateNewLineHeight(true);
        updateLineHeight(newLineHeight);
    });

    // click handler for element with id #down
    $("#down").click(function () {
        var newLineHeight = calculateNewLineHeight(false);
        updateLineHeight(newLineHeight);
    });

    // Function to updated the line height of any
    // 'p' under the paragraph with id '#paragraph' 
    // the newLineHeight is meant to be an number
    var updateLineHeight = function (newLineHeight) {
        // updates the line-height for a paragraph with the new line
        // height (passed in as a parameter) 
        // - let's not forget to add the units of the new line-height
        // (in this case is 'px' for pixels)
        $("#paragraph p").css({
            "line-height": newLineHeight + "px"
        });
    };

    // Function to calculate the new line-height depending on the
    // button clicked (i.e. up or down button)
    var calculateNewLineHeight = function (isUp) {
        // get the existing line of the element 
        var elem = $("#paragraph p");
        var currentLineHeight = $(elem).css("line-height");

        // some browsers return 'normal', instead of a line-height
        // number.  If that's the case, use font size.

        // in either case, we want to remove the units 
        // (in this case 'px') before returning an value
        if( currentLineHeight === 'normal') {
            // use font-size
            currentLineHeight = $(elem).css('font-size');        
            currentLineHeight = Math.floor(parseInt(currentLineHeight.replace('px','')) * 1.5);
        }else{
            currentLineHeight = Math.floor(parseInt(currentLineHeight.replace('px','')));
        }        

        // if the button pressed is 'up' we want to increase the 
        // current line height by 1.5 times.  Otherwise, we decrease
        // it by to 75% of the original value.
        if (isUp) {
            return currentLineHeight * 1.5;
        } else {
            return currentLineHeight * .75;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This is perfect! I am fairly new to jQuery and I was wondering if you could try to explain what each thing you did means.

Comment: @Enin  Certainly! let me add some comments to it